# Search mongodb array for field value on dropdown change

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a dropdown that needs to trigger a findOne for a specific doc in Mongo. I want it to return just the array that it found the value in.

The dropdown html:

```
<select class="form-control" id="saved_config" name="saved_config">
    {{#each currentUser.profile.saved_configs}}
        <option value="{{config}}">{{config}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

That pulls the "config" field value from each "saved_configs" array currently in the current user's profile section.

The dropdown js:

```
"change #saved_config": function(event, template) {
    var selected = $( "#saved_config option:selected" ).text();
    var search = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {'profile.saved_configs.$' : selected});

    console.log(search)

},
```

That listens for the dropdown change and finds one doc that has an "_id" with the current user's id, and searches all arrays in "saved_configs" for the text of the dropdown selection.

The problem is that it is returning the entire doc no matter what value I set "profile.saved_configs.$" as. I would also like for it to return just the array it found the dropdown text in. This way I can easily retrieve the rest of the values in that same array.

Here is the doc architecture -

- _id:
- profile:

  - saved_configs:

    - [Array]
    - [Array]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this functionality](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch)

However, the meteor docs state that: [Field operators such as $ and $elemMatch are not available on the client side yet.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers)

However as you have the full document on the client selecting the correct array in javascript should be simple.  And even if you had Field Operator support, this is all happening client side (and you are not requesting additional data from the server) so there no downside to doing it in javascript as far as I can see.

I'm guessing the structure of the items in saved_configs, but the code would be something like this:

```
"change #saved_config": function(event, template) {
  var selected = $( "#saved_config option:selected" ).text();
  var _search = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.user()._id});
  var search = _search.profile.saved_configs.filter(
       function(config){ 
         return config.name === selected;
       })[0]     // .filter returns array, select first (only) item
  console.log(search)
},
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I didn't know about $elemMatch not being available on client side yet. I was trying to use it, too.